# CoreLocation - Geofence event to start location services

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I'm using `CoreLocation` in my iOS Application. I'm using Significant Location changes and some Geofences. It's currently working well but I would like to improve my location data quality with getting more location updates.

Currently I have one `CLLocationManager` instance running in my application. This single instance is listening geofence and locationUpdates.

As far as I know, significant changes are related to cell tower changes which is enough for me but I have some cases that I need more location data.

I don't want to use `startUpdatingLocation` as it increases the battery consumption but I have an idea about enabling and disabling locationUpdates (while keeping the significant updates open) between the geofences. So, I'm planning to start a secondary instance of `CLLocationManager` when a geofence event occurs. I'll keep that secondary instance running until another Geofence event occurs.

This will help me to get more detailed location data where I need without keeping location services always open.

My question is I don't know if my approach is possible in iOS. In any event of geofence, my app will most like be on background. Can I still enable the secondary `CLLocationManager` start and stop?

I already enabled Background Modes for Location Updates, it's working fine on the current version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need separate CLLocationManager instances. My understanding (and experience) is that geofencing and location updates can coexist in the same CLLocationManager.

Your app can respond to location events in the background, e.g.:

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // were we invoked due to LocationManager event:
    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil {
        printLog( "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey" )

        // We were previously terminated/suspended and need to configure locmgr
        // etc.
        // after this, app will process received location events via
        // didUpdateLocations()
        // didExitRegions()
```